# Running the task after several other tasks completion

Tags: java, concurrency, java-8

Is there a conventional way to run a task after several other tasks completed without keeping separate thread to wait for them?

Comment: You could use a call-back mechanism, such as a property change listener, and then call the last task after all tasks have checked in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use a parallelStream which executes the tasks before continuing (so not waiting as such)

```
tasks.parallelStream().forEach(Runnable::run);
doSomething();
```

Comment: Or [`ExecutorService.invokeAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAll-java.util.Collection-), if more control over the execution is desired…

Answer (score 0):

Define a priority blocking queue and have all your tasks implement comparable interface . Add all the tasks you want to run to the prority queue which will ensure that the tasks with a higher priority will be on top......keep polling the queue.....Now in the case that a higher priority task has not been added to the queue but you still want your task to run after that higher priority task.....have your tasks implement an interface with a single boolean method which will return true if the task should run......put your running condition there.......while polling if the running condition is false add the task back to the priority queue and keep polling.

Comment: I am assuming when you say "run a task after several other tasks completed" you want to follow an order of execution.